# Batch: move - cant find the path specified (adding bat to startup)

Tags: batch-file, startup

Hey trying to add a bat to my startup folder by executing another bat.

setup.bat

```
move "run.bat" "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
pause
```

run.bat

```
echo "k"
pause
```

if i run this normally the error message says:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

if its run as admin:

```
the system cannot find the file specified
```

?

Comment: What part of "the system cannot find the file specified" don't you understand?

Comment: run.bat is in the same directory as setup though, how can it not find the file?

Comment: obviously thats not the code, geez ill edit it

Comment: You should read about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Hiding relevant details helps nobody and only makes it harder to find a solution. Also, you're seeing that error because run.bat and setup.bat aren't in the same directory. Alternatively, %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"` doesn't exist as a directory.

`%appdata%` expands to `C:\Users\Hawk\AppData\Roaming`, so you're actually telling the script to go to `C:\Users\Hawk\AppData\Roaming\\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`, which doesn't exist.

Change setup.bat to

```
move "run.bat" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you 'Run as admin' the current directory is changed. To prove that, temporarily put these 2 lines very near the beginning of your bat file:

```
echo(cd=%cd%
pause
```

Now run it once normally and once as admin and you will see that the current directory is not what you expected. To resolve this I almost always put this line at the beginning of my bat files (before trying to reference any files/folders):

```
pushd %~dp0
```

that will ensure that the current directory is restored to where you started. To prove that, put the above line before your temporary ECHO statement and test again.

Comment: I thought running as admin would not trigger Trojan alerts, but it does. Any ideas?